# How to set time to regular? JAVA

Tags: javascript

Hey how do I set the time to regular time meaning this code:

```
4:00:56 PM
```

rather than what I have set up right now :

```
14:26:00 pm
```

using this script code :

```
function startTime()
{
    var today=new Date();
    var h=today.getHours();
    var m=today.getMinutes();
    var s=today.getSeconds();
    // add a zero in front of numbers<10
    m=checkTime(m);
    s=checkTime(s);
    document.getElementById('txt').innerHTML=h+":"+m+":"+s;
    t=setTimeout(function(){startTime()},500);
}

function checkTime(i)
{
    if (i<10)
    {
        i="0" + i;
    }
        return i;
}
```

Does anybody know how to set the time to regular time using the script above?

Comment: Removing `[JAVA]` tag as it doesn't appear to be related to Java.

Comment: "14 PM"? Where do you live???

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, this code should do it:

```
function startTime()
{
    var today=new Date();
    var h=today.getHours();
    var m=today.getMinutes();
    var s=today.getSeconds();
    var l=timeLabel(h);
    h = timeTo12(h);
    // add a zero in front of numbers<10
    m=checkTime(m);
    s=checkTime(s);
    document.getElementById('txt').innerHTML=h+":"+m+":"+s+l;
    t=setTimeout(function(){startTime()},500);
}

function timeLabel(i)
{
    if (i > 12){
        return " PM";
    }
    return " AM";
}

//Added this function
function timeTo12(i)
{
     if (i > 12){
         i = i - 12;
     }
     return i;
}

function checkTime(i)
{
    if (i<10)
    {
        i="0" + i;
    }
        return i;
}
```

Comment: @user2555791 which part did not work? What is exactly what you want the script to do?

Comment: Your answer still doesn't have the AM / PM portion. Mind if I make a small edit to your code?

Comment: Oh also, `setTimeout(function(){startTime()},...)` can be changed to `setTimeout(startTime,...)`.